# Exporting and reusing binaries during Dockerfile build

Tags: dockerfile

For context, I am trying to convert an existing client/server project into docker containers. This issue concerns the client side of this.

The current setup is a two stage process. I have some personal npm client utilites and I use ‘lit’ in the client.  About every six months or so something in these modules changes and I then run rollup to copy from node_modules to client/libs directory.  If a module in the client/components directory wants to import lit it does something like

import {LitElement, html} from ‘../libs/lit-element.js’

as a result I have no other build stage. I make changes to the source refresh my browser (twice to ensure service worker cache is updated) and I am good to go.  I am trying to replicate this in docker where the client directory is a volume mapped to my client directory.

I have been following the docker build guide but I can’t figure out how to achieve the result. Here is the state so far

```
FROM node:slim AS libraries
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./clientbuild /app
RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:alpine-slim
RUN mount=type=bind,target=./client
COPY —from=libraries /app/libs ./client
RUN mount=type=bind,src=.client,target=/usr/share/nginx/html
```

I’m worried this is correct, as I don’t want to screw my existing code, but right now my internet is down (doing this via mobile hot spot) and I don’t really know what I’m doing

Is this the correct way?

--- EDIT
My internet came back and I ran this.  Apart from `RUN npm build` needing to be `RUN npm run build` I ran to the end.

However my libs are not amongst by source. So I am still puzzled as to what has happened